# Windows 10 desktop icons not showing sporadically

Tags: windows, windows-10, desktop-icons, fences

I use **Windows 10** and [**Fences**](http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/), both using the most recent version.

Sometimes when I boot my computer, desktop icons are not showing and I can't click or select on the desktop. It's just the wallpaper displayed.

This error occurs approximately 20% of the times I start my PC and if it does, I need to reboot my PC in order to access the desktop.

**Is this a known issue to either Windows 10 or Fences?** If so, can it be solved?

**winver**

[image]

Comment: What build of Windows 10 are you using?  I ask because the most **current** version is being rolled to user, so while you might think you have all the updates, you might not actually have `Windows 10 Version 1511`.  If you uninstall Fences do you still have this problem?

Comment: Yes, I use 1511. And I don't know if I had this problem when uninstalling Fences, because like I said, it's pretty sporadically.

Comment: You need to confirm if this problem exists or not if Fences isn't installed.